# writing a decremental array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

This is one of those days where you need a small help on something rather obvious, I need to create an array of decremental years and need to  display five years decrement from current year now it would be like (2012,2011,2010,2009,2008) etc....

I can't think of how to do it in c# any help would be welcome.

Regards

Comment: so you need to know how to make an array of decrementing integers?
Or are these years different objects?

Comment: Arr you looking for ints or DateTimes in your array?

Comment: When you say "five years decrement from current year" I take that to mean the first entry should be current year.  Do you mean that since your example starts last year. Not sure if this is just a forgetting its 2013 problem... ;-)

Comment: the question was answered and I market the answer, look @Botz3000 answer that is what I was looking for. I don't see why people go on editing a question that was answered or saying it is ambiguous, It has an answer and I have marked it FULL STOP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 5, 5).Reverse().ToArray();
```

[`Enumerable.Range(int start, int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) will give you 5 subsequent numbers, starting from 5 years ago. [`Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) reverses the sequence ;) and [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) creates an arrray from it.

Comment: that is what I was looking for grand merci, you are the star of today.

Answer (score 2):

Plain Old C#:

```
int[] ret = new int[5];
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    ret[i] = DateTime.Now.Year - i - 1;
```

With LINQ:

```
var ret = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => DateTime.Now.Year - i - 1).ToArray();
```

[Botz3000 LINQ version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14871362/41360) (better):

```
var ret = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 5, 5).Reverse().ToArray()
```

Comment: This won't start from the current year will it (apologies if I'm being dumb - its early in the morning). Scratch that. The original question is ambiguous in its description and example. :)

Comment: @Chris - the OP asked for 5 years before the current one.

Comment: I'd interpret "five year decrement from this year" as meaning the first should be this year but yeah, I can see that might not be the case. Have commented asking for clarification. :)

Comment: @Chris - His example showed 5 years before the current, therefore I added the `-1` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This will work just fine:

```
var year = DateTime.Today.Year;
var array = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    array[i] = year--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Int32[] GetDecrementalYearsArray(int startWith, int countOfItems)
{
   Int32[] array = new Int32[countOfItems];
   array[0] = startWith;
   for(int i=1;i<countOfItems;i++)
   {
       array[i] = startWith-i;
   }
   return array;
}
```

Comment: Universal, true, yet I cannot get the idea of an `IDecrementalYearsGeneratorFactory` out of my head. XD